# Cannot call method to print

Tags: java

In my code, I need it to take in a letter grade and then it will print out it's corresponding numeric value. The problem I'm having is I can't figure out how to get it to call the method correctly. I feel like I'm close but am confused as to what to do.

```
public class Grade
{
    public static void main( String[ ]  args)
   {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a letter grade: ");
    String letterGrade = input.nextLine();
    Grade number = new Grade(letterGrade);
    double grade = number.getNumericGrade();

    System.out.println("The numberic value is: " 
                       + grade);

    }


public double getNumericGrade(String letterGrade)
    {
        double numericGrade = 0.0;
    if ((letterGrade == "A") || (letterGrade == "A+"))
        numericGrade = 4.0;
    else if (letterGrade == "A-")
        numericGrade = 3.7;
    else if (letterGrade == "B+")
        numericGrade = 3.3;
    else if (letterGrade == "B")
        numericGrade = 3.0;
    else if (letterGrade == "B-")
        numericGrade = 2.7;
    else if (letterGrade == "C+")
        numericGrade = 2.3;
    else if (letterGrade == "C")
        numericGrade = 2.0;
    else if (letterGrade == "C-")
        numericGrade = 1.7;
    else if (letterGrade == "D+")
       numericGrade = 1.3;
    else if (letterGrade == "D")
        numericGrade = 1.0;
    else if (letterGrade == "D-")
        numericGrade = 0.7;
    else if (letterGrade == "F")
        numericGrade = 0.0;
    else 
        numericGrade = -1;
        return numericGrade;
    }     
}
```

Comment: You currently have three problems: 1) you're trying to call a `Grade` constructor with `letterGrade`, but there aren't any constructors taking a string. 2) you're trying to call the `getNumericGrade()` method without any arguments, but it takes a String parameter. 3) You're comparing strings with `==` instead of `equals`.

Comment: Figured it out! Thank you sir. I'm still new to java and it's confusing...